# MySQL Max previous data

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like

```
|---id---|---score---|---avg---|---date---|
|    1   |     20    |    90   |2017-07-24|
|    1   |     13    |    70   |2017-08-24|
|    1   |     21    |    95   |2017-09-24|
|    2   |     10    |    50   |2017-06-24|
|    2   |     17    |    80   |2017-09-24|
```

I want to get the present score(e.g. for 2017-09-24) along with their most recent previous scores.

```
|---id---|prev_score|prev_avg|prev_date |pres_score|pres_avg|pres_date |
|    1   |    13    |   70   |2017-08-24|    21    |   95   |2017-09-24|
|    2   |    10    |   50   |2017-06-24|    17    |   80   |2017-09-24|
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT `id` as `a_id`,
`score` as `pres_score`,
`avg` as `pres_avg`,
`date` as `pres_date`,
(SELECT `score` as `score` FROM `tbl` WHERE `id` = `a_id` AND `date` < `pres_date` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1) as `prev_score`,
(SELECT `avg` as `avg` FROM `tbl` WHERE `id` = `a_id` AND `date` < `pres_date` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1) as `prev_avg`,
(SELECT `date` as `date` FROM `tbl` WHERE `id` = `a_id` AND `date` < `pres_date` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1) as `prev_date`

FROM `tbl` WHERE `date` = '2017-09-24'
```

From what I have tried, I don't think it will give me the result I needed and most of all it's too slow that it's not suitable for large databases.
Can someone help me build a mysql query that can return the desired output of data without decreasing the speed or can run over a massive amount of data.

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Comment: edited my post please help me

Comment: Regarding the performance. Do you have to use just one query to calculate all data? How about this approach? 

- Precalculate max and 2nd max dates for each ID and store them in some temporary table;
- Write intermediate queries that uses precalculated dates for IDs to filter results;
- Build main query as join of 2 sub queries that filter dates by max dates and 2nd max dates.

Comment: What if a user had no score for 9/24?

Comment: then the user will not appear on final recordset

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ugly, but I hope you will get an idea.
I do not have MySQL installation, so some tweaks might be required for MySQL. I used simplified table structure, you can adjust my query to your data structure.

```
create table tbl(
id int,
score int,
avg int,
dat int
)

select q1.id, q1.score as cur_score, q1.avg as cur_avg, q1.dat as cur_date, q2.score as prev_score, q2.avg as prev_avg, q2.dat as prev_date 
from (
select id, score, avg, dat
from tbl t1
where exists (
    select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.id = t1.id 
    group by id
    having max(dat) = t1.dat
)) q1
left join (
    select id, score, avg, dat
    from tbl t1
    where exists (
        select 1 from tbl t2 
        where t2.id = t1.id 
        and t2.dat < (select max(t3.dat) from tbl t3 where t3.id = t1.id)
        group by id
        having max(dat) = t1.dat
    )
) q2 on q1.id = q2.id
```

Comment: i've tried it but it seems also slow for my database. current at 118084 rows in database

Comment: "Slow" does not mean much. What exact part(s) of the query is slow? Did you check execution plan? How your table is indexed? Is it possible to use multiply queries to resolve this problem (precalculate left and right part of the joins, store them in temporary tables and join after that)? Or your options are limited and you have to use just one query?
There are dozens reasons of why it slow and dozens solutions to make it faster.

Comment: In addition, does the query have to output data in this way: 
|---id---|prev_score|prev_avg|prev_date |pres_score|pres_avg|pres_date | ? 
You want to get cur and previous data in one row, it means join which is most probably slow, You can exclude join from query if data if returned as a flat list (current data first, previous data after that). This result set can be processed in Java / PHP / whatever you use and generate table you need by transposing flat list to the table you need.

Comment: I suspect a more elegant solution awaits

Comment: Good luck with waiting... :)

Answer (score 0):

what a challenge weww

try my code then

```
SET @dateTarget := '2017-09-24';

select present.id,
past.score as prev_score,past.avg as prev_avg,past.date as prev_date,
present.score as pres_score,present.avg as pres_avg,present.date as pres_date
from testtb as present
left join (
    select pastMain.id,pastMain.score,pastMain.avg,pastMain.date
    from testtb as pastMain
    inner join (
        select id,max(date) as date
        from testtb 
        where date < @dateTarget
        group by id
    ) as pastWhere on pastMain.id = pastWhere.id and pastMain.date = pastWhere.date
) as past on present.id = past.id
where present.date = @dateTarget;
```

Comment: Why dateTarget is the same for all IDs? In example they are the same, but in real life they can be different for different IDs.

Comment: i look at his try, and saw he search by add date to watch current score and show lastest before that date. then i made a query as his condition. sorry for bad english

Comment: i've tried it but it seems also slow for my database. current at 118084 rows in database